# How does dropbox handle silent data corruption?

Tags: dropbox, data-integrity

How does dropbox handle silent data corruption?

If I have 10 computers synced through dropbox and one day on one of them just some files corrupt unnoticed, will dropbox just sync that 'change' to the other computers?

If so, that would drastically increase the chance of losing data (without noticing it) the more comptuers are synced through dropbox. Does it somehow shield against this? How could it possibly distinguish between an intendet file change and a silent data corruption happening?

Comment: Just an FYI, but Dropbox has it own checksums associated with each file, which can be relatively easy to verify via the Dropbox API and Python. While perhaps not available via the Dropbox client software, there isn't much stopping someone from running a simple script to periodically check for differences in these checksums when there should be none.

Comment: The official Drobox API Python module on PyPI is [here](https://pypi.org/project/dropbox/) and [here is the official documentation (with links) regarding how Dropbox's checksums are created](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/content-hash).

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox syncs via its Web Content (not PC to PC). So you change a file, it goes to Dropbox.com and then syncs back to other computers.

So log into your Dropbox Account and check if any files that you think are corrupted are in the central account.

There is a Dropbox Rewind capability to go back before corrupted files, but I think that is for Dropbox Plus.

See:  https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-installs-integrations/Desktop-saying-Dropbox-files-are-corrupted-but-they-open-on/td-p/304959

Comment: the point of silent data corruption is that you don't notice it happening and maybe you check that file only a year later or so and notice that something is wrong.

Comment: Yes, and I agree with you. The point above to check the web source is to see what might be going on.